Determine the distribution of a random variable $U = X + Y$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables following the same distribution.
How to determine the distribution of $U = X + Y$ ? Is there a general method ?
For example, I know that for a normal or a Poisson distribution, it's simply $U \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$ or $U \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$, but the same cannot be said for an exponential distribution.

It is the 'convolution' of the distributions of $X$ with itself.

$U$  will have mean $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ and (with independence) variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ even if it is not in the same family of distributions.

Take a look here.

When there’s a density, $f_U(u) = \int, f_{XY}(u-y, y), dy$, simplifying when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. See any book on probability.

This is known as Convolutions of Distributions.
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent discrete random variables, then
$$
p_{X+Y}(z)  = \sum_k p_X(k) p_Y(z - k).
$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables, then
$$
f_{X+Y}(z)  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) \, dx.
$$
PROOF OF DISCRETE CONVOLUTION
Assume that $ X$ and $ Y $ are discrete random variables with joint probability mass function $ p_{X,Y} $. That is,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y) = p_{X,Y}(x, y).
$$
We wish to compute the probability mass function of $ Z = X + Y $. For $ z \in \mathbb{Z} $, we calculate
$$
p_Z(z) = \mathbb{P}(Z = z) = \mathbb{P}(X + Y = z).
$$
This can be written as
$$
p_Z(m) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}(X = k, X + Y = z)
= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}(X = k, k + Y = z)
= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y = z - k).
$$
Therefore, the probability mass function of $ Z $ becomes
$$
p_Z(m) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} p_{X,Y}(k, z - k).
$$
In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint p.m.f. factorizes as $ p_{X,Y}(x, y) = p_X(x) \cdot p_Y(y) $, so we obtain
$$
p_Z(m) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} p_X(k) \cdot p_Y(z - k).
$$
Thus, the p.m.f. of the sum $ Z = X + Y $ is the convolution of the p.m.f.s of $ X $ and $Y $.
PROOF OF CONTINUOUS CASE
In the continuous case, notice
$$
F_{X+Y}(z) = \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq z) = \int \int_B f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy,
$$
where $B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x + y \leq z\} $. It follows from independence that the p.d.f. factorises, so
$$
F_{X+Y}(z) = \int \int_B f_X(x) f_Y(y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f_X(x) f_Y(y) \, dx \, dy.
$$
Now, by change of variables $ w = x + y $ and applying Fubini’s Theorem
$$
F_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(w - x) \, dx \, dw.
$$
The result follows by differentiating with respect to $ z $ (c.f. the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Can you explain better the differentiation to get the final result?

To find the PDF of $ Z = X + Y $, differentiate the CDF with respect to $ z $$$
f_{X+Y}(z) = \frac{d}{dz} F_{X+Y}(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \int_{-\infty}^{z} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(w - x) , dx \right) , dw
$$ The inside integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(w - x) , dx$ is thought of as a constant with respect to $ w $. By the second part of the FTC, differentiating $ \int_{-\infty}^{z} g(w) , dw$ with respect to $ z $ yields $ g(z) $.

The distribution is: $$f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(u - x) \, dx$$ for continuous random variables and it is:
$$P(U = u) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty P(X = k) P(Y = u - k)$$
for discrete random variables.
